# How do I compare two generic types in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I need to determine whether an element is the same as the one I'm passing by reference.
In the function `Belongs` I need to compare equality between `d` is and an element of a stored in a dynamic list:

```
struct Nodo{ Dominio dominio; Rando rango; Nodo* next; }; 
typedef Nodo* ptrNodo; 
ptrNodo pri; 

template<class Dominio, class Rango>
bool DicListas<Dominio,Rango>::Belongs(const Dominio &d)
{
  bool retorno = false;
  if(!EsVacia())
  {
    ptrNodo aux=pri;

    while(aux!=NULL)
    {
      if(aux->dominio==d)//-------> THIS CLASS DOESN'T KNOW HOW TO COMPARE THE TYPE DOMINIO.
      {
        retorno = aux->isDef;
      }
      aux = aux->sig;
    }
  }
  return retorno;
}
```

Comment: what does your `Nodo` class look like, and does `bool Domino::operator==(const Domino& d) const` exist?

Comment: You should probably also add a `break;` after `retorno = aux->isDef;`

Comment: What does this have to do with templates? If that class doesn't have comparison, how can you find out whether two instances are equal without generic types involved?

Comment: struct Nodo{
   Dominio dominio;
   Rando   rango;
   Nodo* next;
}; typedef Nodo* ptrNodo;
ptrNodo pri;

Comment: @MooingDuck: If that is true, then a `return aux->isDef` would be much better. Really, the only reason to have `retorno` would be to find the last matching instance.

Comment: is def means that there is a Rango asociated to that dominio.
After I find the Dominio im looking for, then I can check the isDef state.
but for now, I need to find the node first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever *type argument* you provide for the *type parameter* `Dominio`, you've to overload `operator==` for that type.

Suppose, you write this:

```
DicListas<A,B>  obj;
obj.Belongs(A());
```

then you've to overload `operator==` for the type `A` as:

```
class A
{
 public:
    bool operator == (const A &a) const
    {
       //compare this and a.. and return true or false
    }
};
```

Also note that it should be `public` if it's a member function, and better make it `const` function as well, so that you can compare *const* objects of type `A`.

Instead of making it member function, you can make `operator==` a non-member function as well:

```
bool operator == (const A &left, const A & right)
{
     //compare left and right.. and return true or false
}
```

I would prefer the latter.

Comment: ok, but where, Dominio is a struct, shall I do that there? or in the class Im defining the belong function?

Comment: @sbi: Oh.. because it was not a *const* function? I just edited it. Anything else?

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: A struct can have any functions a class can.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the non-member function is a more flexible construct where you've the usual type conversion rules applying for both lhs and rhs. The member operator of course requiring a left hand side as being type A. (yes I tried hard to find a spot to include you've in this comment :) )

Answer (score 2):

It reduces to defining an overload of `operator==` for the user-defined type:

```
bool operator==(const WhateverType &a, const WhateverType &b)
{
    return whatever;
}
```

or maybe as a member of `WhateverType`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare something **about** two, possibly distinct, types, you probably want to look at either [Boost type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/index.html) or the versions of type traits that made it into TR1 and C++11 (if you're using a compiler that supports either TR1 or C++11).

However, that doesn't seem to be the case that you're running into.  In your case, you know that the two objects are of the same type.  In C++, you will get compiler errors if a class you pass as a type parameter to a template does not support all the methods or operators that the template needs.  That's what you're running into.  That's also the problem that concepts are meant to solve (well, concepts are meant to advertise "if you want to use your type with this template, then your type must support ...").  But, unfortunately we didn't get concepts in C++11, so the requirements are implicit.  In your case, as already mentioned, you simply need to make sure that whatever class you pass in as `Dominio` supports `operator==`.

You may also want to look at [Boost concept check](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) to advertise that whatever type is passed in as `Dominio` must support `operator==`.

Comment: I placed the bool operator == (const Dominio &d) in the struct Dominio and it worked, I had to tell the function to return true if the names where the same, comparing this.name against d.name.
Thanks